# Power of an $r$-cycle is an $r$-cycle

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

I'm trying to prove that if $\alpha$ is an $r$-cycle in $S_n$ then $\alpha^k$ is an $r$-cycle if and only if $(k,r)=1$, but I'm having trouble proving that if $(k,r)=1$ then $\alpha^k$ is an $r$-cycle.

Can someone help me with that?

Comment: If $\alpha^k$ is not an $r$-cycle, there is an element $x$ in the cycle $\alpha$ and some positive $s$ which is not a multiple of $r$, such that $(\alpha^k)^s(x)=x$. Thus, $\alpha^{ks}(x)=x$, which implies that $r$ divides $ks$. To get a contradiction, show that this is impossible when $\gcd(k,r)=1$.

Answer (score 2):

For the implication you're looking for. Let $\sigma = \alpha ^k$. Then you're trying to show that if $(k,r)=1$, $o(\sigma)=r$. (Where $o(\sigma)$ denotes the order of $\sigma$). Here are the steps:

1. Show $o(\sigma)|r$, the easy bit.
2. Show $r|o(\sigma)$, the hard bit.

For 2. what you want to do let $m$ be such that $\sigma ^m = id$, and then perform the Euclidean division of $m$ by $r$, to get $q, b$ with $0\le b<r$ such that
$$m = qr + b$$ and somehow determine that $b=0$. Remember that if $(a,b) = 1$ and $a|bk$ then $a|k$.